# executing try block after the exception in try block is handled

Tags: python, valueerror

how to execute the print 'done' statement in the following code:

```
i = 's'
try:
   int(i)
   print 'done'
except ValueError:
   print 's is not an integer'
```

my output is  's is not an integer'

Comment: You can't. It's part of the try block.

Comment: try putting it in a `finally` clause. What do you want to achieve? print done either way?

Comment: @Li357  then how can multiple exceptions within a try block are handled?

Comment: @Ashu_1907 multiple except blocks.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre i want variable i to be stored as a string if it is not a number and if it is a number then add it to a tuple

Comment: @Li357 can you give me the syntax